# XSL Preserve Space in XML CDATA

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace

I've tried a variety of solutions but can't seem to get this working.

I am doing an XSL transformation of XML to XML (FOP) for PDF creation. The source XML has <code> elements whose contents start with a CDATA declaration. The transformation removes newlines.

Example input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<myxml>
    <code><![CDATA[import java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import com.my.library.AClass;
    import com.my.library.AnotherClass;

    public String getStringValue(String key) {
            // Just some ramblings

            // Dummy code...
            if (key != null && key.length() > 0) {
                System.out.println(key);
            }
        }
    ]]></code>
</myxml>
```

Example XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict" 
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="fo" 
    >
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="code"/>
<xsl:preserve-space elements="code" />

<fo:block font-family="Courier New" font-size="12pt" color="black" 
    space-after="12pt" space-before="12pt" space-before.precedence="4">

      <fo:block>
          <xsl:text>Copy</xsl:text>
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="code"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </fo:block>

      <fo:block>
          <xsl:text>Copy Text</xsl:text>
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="code/text()"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </fo:block>

      <fo:block>
          <xsl:text>Original</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="code"/>
      </fo:block>

      <fo:block>
          <xsl:text>Normalise space</xsl:text>
          <value-of select="normalize-space(code)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      </fo:block>

      <fo:block>          
          <xsl:text>Copy with extra CDATA wrapper?</xsl:text>
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<![CDATA[]]></xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="code"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:copy>         
      </fo:block>

      <fo:block>
        <xsl:text>Again, an attempt to wrap</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
          &lt;![CDATA[
        </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="code" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
          ]]&gt;
        </xsl:text>
      </fo:block>
</fo:block>
```

Permutations...
I have tried all permutations of the following:

- Global Declarations: With Both cdata-section and preserve-space, With only one or the other
- Source xml document containing/not containing xml:space="preserve", on both code element and outer element.

In total, 6 permutations.

These settings seem to make little difference for me. The following is output for each test block:

- Block 'Copy': Empty (no text output)
- Block 'Copy Text': Empty (no text output)
- Block 'Original': The code, but all newlines removed
- Block 'Normalise space': Empty (no text output)
- Block 'Copy with extra CDATA wrapper?': Empty (no text output)
- Block 'Again, an attempt to wrap': The code, but all newlines removed

Comment: Your XSLT has no templates, so it's difficult to understand - and impossible to reproduce - what it does. Does this work for you? http://xsltransform.net/bFDb2Cf If not, why not (post the **exact** output you expect to get from this example)?

Comment: Thanks for wanting to present the solution to readers, but destroying the question and replacing with the answer isn't the way to do it. The point of Stack Overflow is to present answers to questions, so if you ask an answer - which is what new readers see - they will be confused as to why you appear to have the answer already, and why people seem to have given you information below that you already know. Instead, if you have an answer, feel free to post that below, so that people can also see the question that gave rise to it. I've rolled back the (otherwise helpful) edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code inside of an fo:block and set the following attributes to control the treatment of whitespace and carriage returns:

- [linefeed-treatment](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#linefeed-treatment)
- [white-space-collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#white-space-collapse)
- [white-space-treatment](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#white-space-treatment)

Like this:

```
<fo:block>
    <xsl:text>Original</xsl:text>
    <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve" 
              white-space-collapse="false" 
              white-space-treatment="preserve">
        <xsl:value-of select="code"/>
    </fo:block>
</fo:block>
```

Answer (score 2):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP. This solution was an edit to the question, so I've rolled that edit back and posted this here.)*

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<solution>
   <solution_name>A Set of Functions</solution_name>
   <description>Just for the sake of example</description>
   <functions>
      <function>
        <code><![CDATA[function String getStringSafely(String textToCheck, String defaultValue) {
                if (textToCheck == null || textToCheck.length() <= 0) {
                    return defaultValue;
                }
                return textToCheck;
            }
        ]]></code>
      </function>
      <function><code><![CDATA[import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import com.example.library.Something;

function String doSomething(String key) {
        if (key == null || key.length() <= 0) {
            return "";
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("Yep, got a value[%1$s]", key));
    }
]]></code>
      </function>
    </functions>
</solution>
```

Example XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/strict" 
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
    exclude-result-prefixes="fo" 
    >
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="code"/>
<xsl:preserve-space elements="code" />
<xsl:template match="solution">
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

  <fo:layout-master-set>
    <fo:simple-page-master master-name="solution-page">
      <fo:region-body margin="1in"/>
    </fo:simple-page-master>
  </fo:layout-master-set>

  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="solution-page">
    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body" id="solution">
        <fo:block text-align="center" 
        space-after="40pt" space-before="100pt" space-after.precedence="3" 
        font-family="Helvetica" font-weight="bold" font-size="14pt" color="#0050B2" >
                <xsl:value-of select="solution_name"/>
        </fo:block>
        <fo:block font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12pt" color="black" 
    space-after="12pt" space-before="12pt" space-before.precedence="4">
            <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
        </fo:block>
        <xsl:for-each select="functions">
            <xsl:variable name="this" select="." />
            <xsl:call-template name="solution_functions">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$this"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:flow>
  </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="solution_functions">
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
  <fo:block id="functions" break-before="page" 
            font-family="Helvetica"
            font-weight="bold"
            font-size="14pt"
            color="#0050B2" space-after="12pt"
            space-before="16pt" space-after.precedence="3">
        Functions
  </fo:block>
    <xsl:for-each select="$data/function">
        <xsl:variable name="this" select="." />
        <xsl:call-template name="present_function">
            <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$this"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="present_function">
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
    <fo:block 
                font-family="Helvetica"
                font-weight="bold"
                font-size="12pt" 
                space-after="12pt"
                space-before="16pt" space-after.precedence="3">
            Code
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12pt" color="black" 
        space-after="12pt" space-before="12pt" space-before.precedence="4">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:text>This works! Thanks ...</xsl:text>
            <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve" 
                      white-space-collapse="false" 
                      white-space-treatment="preserve">
                <xsl:value-of select="$data/code"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:block>
    <fo:block>
       [ All following examples were part of the original post. The above is the one which works. The below, kept for future reference to original question. ]
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:text>Original</xsl:text>
        <fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve" 
                  white-space-collapse="false" 
                  white-space-treatment="preserve">
            <xsl:value-of select="$data/code"/>
        </fo:block>
    </fo:block>

      <fo:block>
          <xsl:text>Copy</xsl:text>
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="$data/code"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </fo:block>

      <fo:block>
          <xsl:text>Copy Text</xsl:text>
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="$data/code/text()"/>
          </xsl:copy>
      </fo:block>

      <fo:block>
          <xsl:text>Original</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="$data/code"/>
      </fo:block>

      <fo:block>
          <xsl:text>Normalise space</xsl:text>
          <value-of select="normalize-space($data/code)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      </fo:block>

      <fo:block>          
          <xsl:text>Copy with extra CDATA wrapper?</xsl:text>
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<![CDATA[]]></xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="$data/code"/>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:copy>         
      </fo:block>

      <fo:block>
        <xsl:text>Again, an attempt to wrap</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
          &lt;![CDATA[
        </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$data/code" />
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
          ]]&gt;
        </xsl:text>
      </fo:block>

    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: OP (or anyone else), if I have not captured the correct essence of the solution, please do amend this CW post.

Answer (score 1):

**Let's clear up a few fundamental misunderstandings reflected in your code.**

1. As @michael.hor257k mentioned, you have no `xsl:template`
   constructs.  This is actually ok for simplified stylesheets that
   you're attempting, but such form has no `xsl:stylesheet` root
   element; it simply begins with the XML root element desired in your
   output XML.  It then pulls from the input XML as you're doing with
   `xsl:value-of/@select` constructs.   So, major fix #1 is to add
   `<xsl:template match="/">...` or remove `<xsl:stylesheet>`.   We'll
   go with the second option (simplified stylesheets) since it seems to be what you've favoring.
2. Next, realize that your XPaths are failing to select anything, so
   all of your test cases aren't proving anything.  Major fix #2: Rather than
   selecting `"code/'`, select `"/myxml/code"` in all of your test
   cases.

**Here are your test cases with the above changes (and a few other minor fixes) made:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<fo:block font-family="Courier New" font-size="12pt" color="black" 
          space-after="12pt" space-before="12pt" space-before.precedence="4"
          xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
          xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
          xsl:version="1.0">
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:text>Copy</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="/myxml/code"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </fo:block>
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:text>Copy Text</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="/myxml/code/text()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </fo:block>
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:text>Original</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="/myxml/code"/>
  </fo:block>
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:text>Normalise space</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(code)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </fo:block>
  <fo:block>          
    <xsl:text>Copy with extra CDATA wrapper?</xsl:text>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<![CDATA[]]></xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="/myxml/code"/>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>         
  </fo:block>
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:text>Again, an attempt to wrap</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
      &lt;![CDATA[
    </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="/myxml/code" />
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">
      ]]&gt;
    </xsl:text>
  </fo:block>
</fo:block>
```

**Running the above XSLT against your input XML yields more useful test results:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><fo:block xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family="Courier New" font-size="12pt" color="black" space-after="12pt" space-before="12pt" space-before.precedence="4"><fo:block>Copyimport java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import com.my.library.AClass;
    import com.my.library.AnotherClass;

    public String getStringValue(String key) {
            // Just some ramblings

            // Dummy code...
            if (key != null &amp;&amp; key.length() &gt; 0) {
                System.out.println(key);
            }
        }
    </fo:block><fo:block>Copy Textimport java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import com.my.library.AClass;
    import com.my.library.AnotherClass;

    public String getStringValue(String key) {
            // Just some ramblings

            // Dummy code...
            if (key != null &amp;&amp; key.length() &gt; 0) {
                System.out.println(key);
            }
        }
    </fo:block><fo:block>Originalimport java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import com.my.library.AClass;
    import com.my.library.AnotherClass;

    public String getStringValue(String key) {
            // Just some ramblings

            // Dummy code...
            if (key != null &amp;&amp; key.length() &gt; 0) {
                System.out.println(key);
            }
        }
    </fo:block><fo:block>Normalise space</fo:block><fo:block>Copy with extra CDATA wrapper?<![CDATA[import java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import com.my.library.AClass;
    import com.my.library.AnotherClass;

    public String getStringValue(String key) {
            // Just some ramblings

            // Dummy code...
            if (key != null &amp;&amp; key.length() &gt; 0) {
                System.out.println(key);
            }
        }
    ]]></fo:block><fo:block>Again, an attempt to wrap
      <![CDATA[
    import java.nio.charset.Charset;
    import com.my.library.AClass;
    import com.my.library.AnotherClass;

    public String getStringValue(String key) {
            // Just some ramblings

            // Dummy code...
            if (key != null &amp;&amp; key.length() &gt; 0) {
                System.out.println(key);
            }
        }

      ]]>
    </fo:block></fo:block>
```

**I believe from there you'll be able to identify the test case results that produce the results you seek.**